# Optimization with Linear constraint $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I confront with this problem:

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \dfrac{1}{2} \left\| x- a \right\|_{2}^{2}$$
subject to $$Ax=0.$$

My tactic is to use Lagrange multiplier method that:

$$\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left\| x- a \right\|_{2}^{2} - \lambda (Ax).$$

Then, $$\nabla_{x} \mathcal{L} = (x-a)-A^{T} \lambda.$$

If I set this $\nabla_{x} \mathcal{L} = 0$, I obtain $x = a + A^{T} \lambda$. However, it seems this is not the solution to the problem because I have not eliminated the $\lambda$ in my solution. Yet, I have to prove this $x$ is the minimizer.

Any helps will much be appreciated.

Comment: In your expression ${\cal L}(x,\lambda) = \frac{1}{2}\|x-a\|_2^2 - \lambda (Ax),$ the first summand is a scalar, the second summand is a vector. This doesn't go together. I think, you can argue as follows. The condition $Ax = 0$ confines $x$ to a linear subspace. Now we all know that $\|x-a\|_2$ is minimal for $x =$ "the orthogonal projection of $a$ onto that subspace".

Comment: @jflipp Thanks for your comment. I understand I should not put the scalar and the vector together but I am not sure how to formulate the Lagrangian function. Would you please give me a hint? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that the rows of $A$ are independent. Thus, $ m \leq n$ (otherwise the problem is infeasible).
The problem is equivalent to the known convex one

$$minimize \hspace{3mm}\|\mathbf{y}\|_{2}^2$$
$$s.t.  \hspace{3mm} A\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{b},$$ where

$\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{a}$, and $\mathbf{b} = -A\mathbf{a}$.

If $m = n$, the solution is $\mathbf{y}^{\star} = A^{-1}\mathbf{b} \Rightarrow \mathbf{x}^{\star} =- A^{-1}A\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{a} \Rightarrow \mathbf{x}^{\star} = \mathbf{0}.$

If $ m < n:$

Lagrangain function: $\mathcal{L} = \|\mathbf{y}\|_{2}^2 + \lambda(A\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{b})$. Thus,

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{y}} = 2\mathbf{y}^T+\lambda A = \mathbf{0} \Rightarrow \mathbf{y} = -\frac{1}{2}\lambda A^T \Rightarrow A\mathbf{y} = -\frac{1}{2}\lambda AA^T \Rightarrow $$
$$\mathbf{b} = -\frac{1}{2}\lambda AA^T.$$

Since $rank(A) = m < n$, the matrix $AA^T$ is invertible. Thus, $\lambda = -2(AA^T)^{-1}\mathbf{b}$.

Substituting $\lambda$ in $\mathbf{y}$ expression, we have
$$ \mathbf{y}^{\star} = A^T (AA^T)^{-1}\mathbf{b}.$$

On $\mathbf{x}:$
$$ \mathbf{x}^{\star} = \left[-A^T (AA^T)^{-1}A + I\right]\mathbf{a}.$$

Source: *Convex Optimization (S. Boyd and L. Vendenberghe).*

Comment: Thank you Alex. I understand how to proceed now. Your answer is very clear. I appreciate your help =)

Comment: You're welcome! I've just changed the case $m=n$ in order to explicit $x$. :)

Comment: Thanks again and I understand the concept now.